# Is it bad practice to wrap a new SqlConnection instance in a static method?

Tags: c#, static, sqlconnection

I have created a static method that can be called from a DataLayer, in order to fetch data. I realize that if you are doing a Singleton for the SQLConnection is very bad since there might be concurrent users, and I have the connection pool taking care of this.

I have created this method static simply not to init the method each time.

```
  public static DataSet Fetch(String DataSet, String StoredProcedure, String SrcTable)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet(DataSet);

        using (SqlConnection conn = new ConnectionClass().Connection)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(StoredProcedure, conn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        adapter.Fill(ds, SrcTable);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    conn.Close();
            }

            if (DatabaseUtils.DataSetIsNotEmpty(ds))
                return ds;
        }

        throw new NoRowsReturnedException("Database has returned no rows");
    }
```

Does this approach break in a deployed enviornment?

Comment: My two cents: *no static methods* (or very, very few - and not for this - look at DI/IoC)

Comment: Yes I am aware of IoC. I was doubtful if i should be using ioc due to the fact that there will not be a lot of database operations...we'll see. Thanks for the pointer though

Comment: @AlbertHerd It's not a lot of database operations *today*, but will it be *tomorrow*?  I've seen applications start off as intern pet projects and blow up into enterprise-wide tools.

Answer (score 2):

The method is fine but all the try/catch/finally is not needed. This is what "using" does. Let alone that you have potential null reference if the conn object is not constructed successfully.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine to make this method static if you like. The problem with the design is that you cannot replace it in testing, for example. All client code is physically bound to a static class. That's what I normally avoid in my code.

One more suggestion: Do not dispose connection returned by the `ConnectionClass`. In that way, `ConnectionClass` object becomes invalid. Instead, make the whole `ConnectionClass` disposable, something like this:

```
public class ConnectionClass : IDisposable
{
    private SqlConnection conn;

    private void Connect()
    {
        if (conn == null)
        {
            // connect
        }
    }

    public SqlCommand CreateCommand(string spName)
    {
        Connect();
        return this.conn.CreateCommand(StoredProcedure, spName);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (conn != null)
        {
            conn.Dispose();
            conn = null;
        }
    }
}
```

In this way, `ConnectionClass` is responsible for establishing and closing the connection. Also, remove `Class` from the class name - it's of no use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything that will break in production.  Whether or not it's a good idea depends on your problem domain and how the data you retrieve correlates with it.

If all you're doing is grabbing a result set and spitting it up on a screen or into a file then yeah, go ahead.  You're treating the fetching of the results as a utility, which is in many cases not unlike logging, or a Math function.  It's quick, dirty, and gets the job done with less effort.  Retrieving data may not necessarily be integral to your problem domain.  It's just a function you need to solve the problem your code addresses.  An example of this would be building a set of reports for management.  The data matters but isn't integral to the problem domain as you're performing aggregations and spitting out raw data at most.

If your application needs to understand each row of your result as an object and start working with that data in more meaningful ways, you would want to treat accessing the database less as a utility and more of an integral part of your problem domain. This is where you'd want to start looking at things like the Repository patter.  You'd be taking a more object-oriented approach, and as a result would not want to use static methods/classes. An example of this would be an Inventory management system where working with individual items in the system is integral to the system's function.

Ask yourself these questions and you should be able to find the answer.  From a purely coding perspective, your code appears functional.